# What macro extensions tubes are compatible with Nikon AF-S?

Tags: nikon, macro, extension-tubes

I am looking for a set of macro extension tubes for a Nikon D40 that will work with the AF-S system (i.e. will send all the relevant stuff between lens and body for full auto operation).

I have found lots of extension tubes online, but they tend not to have much detail associated with them and I can't find any that are compatible with the AF-S set up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any tubes that say that they have the electrical contacts should work with the AF-S system.
[I have the Zeikos Extension tubes.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003IVZVDO)  They work great, fit well, work with AF-S lenses, and transmit all the various information.  I have no particular issues with them at all.

Comment: In reality, folks don't use autofocus much in macro - but the aperture control sure is nice.

Comment: Perhaps they don't use AF much for macro photography, but they *do* use it quite a bit when the tubes are being used to enhance the close-focus capability of longer lenses (something birders do quite a bit). At least on the shorter tubes, AF pass-through can be a very useful thing to have.

Comment: @Stan - OooooOOO interesting point!

Answer (score 1):

The [Kenko Extension Tube Set](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/375238-REG/Kenko_AEXTUBEDGN_Auto_Extension_Tube_Set.html) is another seemingly well-regarded brand that retains AF compatibility, though it is significantly more expensive than the Zeikos tube set (with purportedly better build quality - which might be important if you plan to hang a long heavy lens off of them).

Like the Zeikos set, it includes 12mm, 20mm, and 36mm tubes that can be used alone or in combination with each other.

I don't own either set, but have recently been researching for myself.