# How do I set the aperture of a Nikon lens when using extension tubes?

Tags: nikon, aperture, lens-mount

I bought extension tubes to do some macro photography. The problem I am facing is that the tubes I got disconnect the aperture from the camera settings. So, I thought I will fix the aperture, disconnect the lens, put extension tubes in between, and connect the lens back. But the aperture always snaps to the smallest possible (f/32 in my case) when I try to disconnect the camera resulting in heavily underexposed images.

So the question is, how do you disconnect the lens, without moving the aperture size while doing it? I am using Nikon D3300. Lens is Nikon DX VR AF-P Nikkor 18:55mm 1: 3.5 :5.6G. The default one that comes with the camera.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What macro extensions tubes are compatible with Nikon AF-S?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15414/what-macro-extensions-tubes-are-compatible-with-nikon-af-s)

Comment: @scottbb Are you suggesting that getting a different set of extension tubes is the only answer?

Comment: Related, but doesn't solve your problem (only for *reversing* the lens, not mounting on extension tubes): [Is there a way to adjust the aperture of a Nikon lens without a camera or physical aperture ring?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/49978/11924)

Comment: @mattdm with G lenses, yes.

Comment: @scottbb Sounds like altogether that makes an answer. (I guess the other possibility is to find a non-G lens? I don't know Nikon that well.)

Comment: You set the aperture directly on the lens, with its aperture ring.  However G lenses do not have the aperture ring, so they are not the choice to use with extension tubes.   However, there are extension tubes (Kenko) that do still work automatically, even with G lenses.

Comment: Or you could get a Canon EOS with electronically controlled servo actuated aperture control. With the lens attached to the powered on camera, just set the aperture you want manually, then remove the lens while holding down the DoF preview button. The lens will stay at that aperture until reconnected to a powered on EOS camera. :-)

Comment: This is the behaviour I initially asked for. Will post another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: you need tubes that have electrical contacts and aperture control linkage pass-through to control your "G" lens's aperture.

Nikon lenses that are not the "**E**" (electronic aperture) type have mechanically-actuated apertures. The lens has a spring-loaded aperture control lever that is controlled by a matching aperture control lever in the camera body.

Nikon "**G**" lenses, being a non-E lens, require mechanical aperture control. The "G" designates lenses without aperture control rings. Thus, the only way to control the aperture in "G" lenses is by the camera body, or some device that mounts on the lens and mechanically moves the aperture lever, such as the [Nikon BR-6](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/lens-bellows/-6-auto-diaphragm-ring-for-pb-4,-5.html) auto diaphragm ring, or the [Photodiox Nikon G Aperture Control Enabler](https://www.fotodioxpro.com/nikong-aperture-control-enabler-for-nikon-g-dx-lenses.html).

(*Note*: both of the mentioned adapters are for reverse-mounted lenses, with the lens mount being exposed towards the subject, not for using inline between lens and body).

There are a few brands of extension tubes available with electrical contacts that pass signals between the body and the lens. The electrical contacts are necessary because even the aperture linkage is mechanical, the camera will not control the aperture if it doesn't know there is a lens attached. The identification of the lens is through the electrical contacts.

Thus, in order to control the aperture of "G" lenses mounted on extension tubes, the tubes must have electrical contacts to pass signals between the camera body and lens.

Below is a non-exhaustive list of tubes currently available that will work with "G" lenses (links go to brand websites, not retailers):

- [Vello Auto Extension Tube Set for Nikon](http://www.vellogear.com/camera-accessories/lens-extension-tubes/auto-extension-tube-set-for-nikon)
- [Kenko DG Teleplus Extension Tube Set](http://www.kenkotokinausa.com/products/kenko/slrc-04.html)
- [Xit Pro Series Extension Tube Set for Nikon](http://xit-group.com/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=206)
- [Meike MK-N-AF-A Metal Auto Focus AF Macro Extension Tube Set for Nikon Camera](http://www.meikestore.com/product/meike-mk-n-af-a-metal-auto-focus-af-macro-extension-tube-set-for-nikon-camera/1221.html)

There are several other brands that don't have their own websites, that can be found on Amazon, B&H, Adorama, etc.

*Disclosure*: I own and use the Xit tubes. They work fine, and I have not had any problems with them.

Comment: I have those Meike tubes.  They work great with all of my lens.  My only issue is the plastic mounts scare the heck out of me at times.

Comment: Thanks for stopping by and explaining it to me. Subquestion..what if I wanted to disconnect the lens and have aperture fixed at that size? What kind of lens do I need for that? For example while shooting timelapses, it is mandatory to disconnect the lens, otherwise you get a slight flickr.

Comment: @sanjihan That's an entirely different question. Rather than ask it in comments (which are not for extended back-and-forth question and answer), please [ask a new question](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @sanjihan You need a Canon EOS lens for that. :-)

Comment: Is it possible to achieve that with Nikon lens?